Why does TGRASS GIS always issue missing tgis warning?
Fairly new to GRASS, but not GIS. Using GRASS 8.3.2 Windows GUI interface.
I'm trying to build an STRDS in a mapset other than PERMANENT. After importing the maps I call up t.connect from the main menu, and immediately the following warning appears in the command window even before the dialog appears on screen:
GRASS_INFO_WARNING(32296,13): Temporal database connection defined as:
GRASS_INFO_WARNING(32296,13): D:\Data\grassdata/Andes/PERMANENT/tgis/sqlite.db
GRASS_INFO_WARNING(32296,13): But database file does not exist.
Fortunately a subsequent t.create command appears to succeed and the database is created in the correct place. However, each time I run a command against the DB the same warning is issued, sometimes many times. What is going on? Do I need to set some external variable?
